# SED { command fail

Tags: sed, mks

On MKS SED for Windows, this

```
TYPE Q:\temp\curtainssetspread.M3U | SED -E "/z/{s_a_b_}"
```

fails with

```
sed: garbage after command
```

Why?

This usage accords correctly with docs:

```
a,b{    groups all commands until the next matching }, so that sed executes the entire group only if the { command is selected by its address(es).
```

Comment: I'm not sure about peculiarities of MKS sed, but `s_a_b` is just a single command and POSIX sed would accept `/z/s_a_b_` without curly braces. Try inserting `;` before the closing brace, that fixes some problems in BSD sed.

Comment: Also, any reason why you're using underscores instead of slashes?

Comment: @Benjamin To reduce escaping. Underscore less frequently appears inside the delimited string than slash. And I find underscore leaves the delimitation more visible.

Comment: @Benjamin, inserting ; before the closing brace does fix it. Because using ; as a command separator is undocumented for MKS SED https://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man1/sed.1.asp I think HTNW's is the strictly better workaround. But your implied "Because ; is missing" is the best answer, so please post it as an answer for me to tick.

Comment: @SLePort, that doesn't necessitate change of delimiter from slash. Only Slash inside the regexp or replacement would.

Answer (score 1):

According to [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html), the `}` must be preceded by a newline. I'm not sure what MKS does, but the beauty of having a standard is that the following should work on *all* systems (using multiple `-e`s joins each string together with newlines in between):

```
sed -e "/z/{s_a_b_" -e "}"
```

If it doesn't work, it's a bug in MKS and should be reported, as they say their `sed` is POSIX-compliant.

I do suggest following Benjamin's advice and just doing

```
sed -e '/z/s_a_b_'
```

if possible, though.

Comment: No one saw that >_<

Comment: It does work on MKS SED, despite that ' (using multiple -es joins each string together with newlines in between)' is undocumented behaviour https://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man1/sed.1.asp . Thanks.

Comment: "they say their sed is POSIX-compliant". They imply it, but I'd like to see where they actually state it.

Comment: At the very end of [the man page](https://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man1/sed.1.asp), in the "Portability" section, they say they support POSIX.

Comment: The verb 'support' is conspicuously absent :) http://www.mkssoftware.com/support/kb/faqs.asp?product=Toolkit#art19 is inconclusive. Given the stated objectives, I can't see they'd want SED to be POSIX compatible for good reason, but they're not saying it is, and I wonder if that too is for good reason. I.e. it isn't.

Comment: Does it matter? There's no reason for an attempt at Windows interop to somehow break POSIX sed's `-e`. Very few systems that call themselves POSIX-compliant actually are, in all respects, but those are controlled deviations, usually. Anyway, there's no phrase saying "`-e` won't append its argument to the script with a newline," explicitly, but they *do* state POSIX-compliance, so they state that `-e` works this way by proxy.

Comment: "Does it matter?" Yes compatibility matters. "they do state POSIX-compliance" Nowhere that I can see.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152473/discussion-between-htnw-and-chrisjj).